# Error Traducion ficheros por trozos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas estoy intentando realizar una traducción de ficheros en varios trozos separados para luego unirlos, me esta funcionando bien pero no se por que motivo cuando llega a el 3 fichero a traducir me da este error, estoy cogiendo al lista individual del fallo que me da y haciéndolo sola me lo hace también sin problema, así que no parece que sea por falta de algún valore o carácter extraño.

```
files = recorrer_archivos(path)

    for i in files:
        hdl = open(f"{path}{i}", 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig')
        print('Leeo Fichero')
        print(i)
        print('-----------------------------')
        print('Leeo Lineas del fichero')
        leo_lineas = hdl.readlines()
        print(leo_lineas)
        print('-----------------------------')
        print('Leeo longitud lineas del fichero')
        longitud_lineas = len(open(f"{path}{i}", 'r',  encoding='utf-8-sig').readlines())
        print(longitud_lineas)
        print('-----------------------------')
        print('Mitad Lineas')
        mitad_lineas = math.ceil(longitud_lineas / 3)
        print(mitad_lineas)
        print('-----------------------------')
        print('Separacion de lectura lineas')
        num = mitad_lineas
        suma = 0
        list = []
        while suma < longitud_lineas:
            suma = suma + num
            list.append(suma)
        print(list)
        print('-----------------------------')
        print('Creamos Dicionario')
        dictOfWords = {i: list[i] for i in range(0, len(list))}
        print(dictOfWords)
        print('-----------------------------')

        u = 0
        print('Leemos ficheros en trozos Y Guardamos')
        for key, value in dictOfWords.items():
            inicio = u
            final = value + 1
            convertir = leo_lineas[inicio:final]
            print(convertir)
            spain = translator.translate(convertir, dest='es')
            for translation in spain:
                print(translation.text)
            u = value + 1
         print('-----------------------------')
```

Este es el error que recibo:

```
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: hola, tal vez esta respuesta te ayude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0, un saludo

Comment: Gracias parece que tengo el error el problema es que necesito reiniciar el translator por cada trocito que lee si no los lee todos seguidos y da un pete por el limite de la API a ver como puedo realizar eso para que me los vaya leyendo trocito a o trozo y me reinicie el translator.